# Replace outlier values with NaN in numpy? (preserve length of array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of magnetometer data with artifacts every two hours due to power cycling.
[image: Magnetometer data, produced using plotly.express, with outliers due to power cycling.]

I'd like to replace those indices with NaN so that the length of the array is preserved.

Here's a code example, adapted from https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/02/removing-outliers-standard-deviation-python.html.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# For pulling data from CDAweb:
from ai import cdas
import datetime

# Import data:
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 24, 0, 0, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 25, 0, 0, 0)
data = cdas.get_data(
                    'sp_phys',
                    'THG_L2_MAG_'+ 'PG2',
                    start,
                    end,
                    ['thg_mag_'+ 'pg2']
                )

x =data['UT']
y =data['VERTICAL_DOWN_-_Z']


def reject_outliers(y):   # y is the data in a 1D numpy array
    n = 5  # 5 std deviations
    mean = np.mean(y)
    sd = np.std(y)
    final_list = [x for x in y if (x > mean - 2 * sd)]
    final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < mean + 2 * sd)]
    return final_list

px.scatter(reject_outliers(y))

print('Length of y: ')
print(len(y))
print('Length of y with outliers removed (should be the same): ')
print(len(reject_outliers(y)))
px.line(y=y, x=x)
# px.scatter(y) # It looks like the outliers are successfully dropped.
# px.line(y=reject_outliers(y), x=x)   # This is the line I'd like to see work.
```

When I run 'px.scatter(reject_outliers(y))', it looks like the outliers are successfully getting dropped:
[image: Scatter plot indicating that outliers are successfully being dropped.]
...but that's looking at the culled y vector relative to the index, rather than the datetime vector x as in the above plot. As the debugging text indicates, the vector is shortened because the outlier values are dropped rather than replaced.

How can I edit my 'reject_outliers()` function to assign those values to NaN, or to adjacent values, in order to keep the length of the array the same so that I can plot my data?

Answer (score 0):

Use else in the list comprehension along the lines of:

```
[x if x_condition else other_value for x in y]
```

Comment: Hmm..... I tried replacing `final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < mean + 2 * sd)]` with `final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < mean + 2 * sd) else np.nan]`, but I get a syntax error pointing to the start of  `else`. What am I missing?

Comment: The syntax required is precise. Try: final_list = [x if (x < (mean + 2 * sd)) else np.nan for x in final_list] The "for  x in..." moves to the end to get the logic right.

Answer (score 0):

Got a less compact version to work. Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# For pulling data from CDAweb:
from ai import cdas
import datetime

# Import data:
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 24, 0, 0, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 25, 0, 0, 0)
data = cdas.get_data(
                    'sp_phys',
                    'THG_L2_MAG_'+ 'PG2',
                    start,
                    end,
                    ['thg_mag_'+ 'pg2']
                )

x =data['UT']
y =data['VERTICAL_DOWN_-_Z']


def reject_outliers(y):   # y is the data in a 1D numpy array
    mean = np.mean(y)
    sd = np.std(y)
    final_list = np.copy(y)
    for n in range(len(y)):
        final_list[n] = y[n] if y[n] > mean - 5 * sd else np.nan
        final_list[n] = final_list[n] if final_list[n] < mean + 5 * sd else np.nan
    return final_list

px.scatter(reject_outliers(y))

print('Length of y: ')
print(len(y))
print('Length of y with outliers removed (should be the same): ')
print(len(reject_outliers(y)))
# px.line(y=y, x=x)

px.line(y=reject_outliers(y), x=x)   # This is the line I wanted to get working - check!
```

[image: Magnetometer results with outliers eliminated, plotted successfully with respect to time.]

Comment: Good that you got it working. I've provided comment to correct your syntax for the comprehension approach - which is worth noting as it is often useful.

Answer (score 0):

More compact answer, sent via email by a friend:

In numpy you can select/index based on a Boolean array, and then make assignment with it:

```
def reject_outliers(y):   # y is the data in a 1D numpy array

    n = 5  # 5 std deviations

    mean = np.mean(y)

    sd = np.std(y)

    final_list = y.copy()

    final_list[np.abs(y - mean) > n * sd] = np.nan

    return final_list
```

I also noticed that you didn’t use the value of n in your example code.

Alternatively, you can use the where method (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
np.where(np.abs(y - mean) > n * sd, np.nan, y)
```

You don’t need the .copy() if you don’t mind modifying the input array.

Replace np.mean and np.std with np.nanmean and np.nanstd if you want the function to work on arrays that already contain nans, i.e. if you want to use this function recursively.

The answer about using if else in a list comprehension would work, but avoiding the list comprehension makes the function much faster if the arrays are large.